# Debian netinstall with ip and gateway from different subnets on XenServer

Tags: debian, xen, subnet

How to setup Debian netinstall with ip and gateway from different subnets on XenServer?

Answer (score 0):

You need a bridge interface to the other subnet and configure you VM's on it